# use titlesec in biditufte class

Tags: titlesec

I want to specialize sectoining in persian biditufte class.
I use this code in report class but in biditufte-handout class I got an error.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\definecolor{sec}{HTML}{DD5C14}
\definecolor{band}{HTML}{EE9C52}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}{}{0.5ex}%
  {\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}%
  \noindent
  \color{band}%
  \llap{\vrule width\textwidth height1ex depth0ex\hskip0.75ex}%
  \textcolor{sec}{\unskip#1}%
  \hskip0.75ex%
  \rlap{\vrule width\textwidth height1ex depth0ex}%
\end{minipage}}[\smallskip]


\usepackage[Kashida]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Language=Default]{Persian Modern}
\setdigitfont{Persian Modern}

\begin{document}
\section[\rl{اولین هدر} ]{\rl{اولین\\  بخش}}

مقداری متن برای اولین بخش

\end{document}
```

Is there any solution to use titlesec in this class? if not what can I do to change all sectoins like above code?

thanks.

Comment: What did the error say?

Comment: You could put `\PassOptionsToPackage{explicit}{titlesec}` before `\documentclass` but if the class is using `titlesec` in a way that is incompatible with that, you'd need egreg's approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `biditufte-handout` class already loads `titlesec` without the `explicit` option, so you can't load it again with the option.

It's not a big problem: without the `explicit` option, the last mandatory argument to `\titleformat` can be either empty or a macro that takes an argument, which the section title will be passed to.

However, one has also to override the `\titleformat` instruction issued by the class, delaying the new one at begin document.

```
\documentclass{biditufte-handout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{sec}{HTML}{DD5C14}
\definecolor{band}{HTML}{EE9C52}

\newcommand{\dosection}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}
  \noindent
  \color{band}%
  \llap{\vrule width\textwidth height1ex depth0ex\hskip0.75ex}%
  \textcolor{sec}{\unskip#1}%
  \hskip0.75ex
  \rlap{\vrule width\textwidth height1ex depth0ex}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \titleformat{\section}[hang]
    {\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
    {}
    {0.5ex}
    {\dosection}
    [\smallskip]%
}

\usepackage[Kashida]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Language=Default]{Persian Modern}
\setdigitfont{Persian Modern}

\begin{document}
\section[\rl{اولین هدر} ]{\rl{اولین\\  بخش}}

مقداری متن برای اولین بخش

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice!

if I want to learn Tex & LaTex like you what should I do?!